# Systems of linear differential equation for projectile motion

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose that a mass m is fired by a gun with an angle of $\theta$ with the horizontal and suppose that the initial velocity of the mass is $v_0$ feet per second. Neglect all forces except gravity and air resistance. Air resistance is equal to the $k$ $\times$ velocity of the object in (ft/sec).

1) Take the origin as the position of the gun and x-axis as horizontal and y-axis as vertical. Show that the differential equation of the resulting motion are

$$m\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}+k\frac{dx}{dt}=0$$

$$m\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}+k\frac{dy}{dt}+mg=0 $$

2) Find the solution fo the systems of differential equation in (1)

My work,

I have drawn a diagram and solve for (1). The motion of the object is upwards so air resistance is acting opposite to the motion of the object. Gravity is always downwards.

I am not sure how to do the (2) one.

$$(mD^2+kD)x=0$$

$$x=c_1+c_2e^{\frac{-kt}{m}}$$

$$(mD^2+kD)y=-mg$$

$$y=k_1+k_2e^{\frac{-kt}{m}}-\frac{mgt}{k}$$

Comment: You can also solve these equations by letting $p=\dot x$ and $q=\dot y$. Note that $v_0=|\vec{v}(0)|=|(\dot{x}(0),\dot{y}(0))|$

Comment: ... and $\vec{v}(0)=(v_1(0)\cos\theta,v_2(0)\sin\theta)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
(mD^2+kD)y &=& -mg \\
(mD+k)y &=& C-mgt \\
(D+\frac km)y &=& C'-gt \\
e^{kt/m}(D+\frac km)y &=& C'e^{kt/m}-gte^{kt/m} \\
D(e^{kt/m}y) &=& C'e^{kt/m}-gte^{kt/m} \\
e^{kt/m}y &=& C''e^{kt/m}-\frac mkgte^{kt/m} + \frac{m^2}{k^2}ge^{kt/m} + D \\
y &=& C'' - \frac mkgt + \frac{m^2}{k^2}g + De^{-kt/m} \\
\end{array}$$

Comment: How about the $\theta$ in the equations and $v_0$ too?

Comment: @Crazy those are initial values that you subtitute into the solution to find the constants.

Comment: I am not sure how to deal with the $\theta$ as the initial condition.

Comment: @Crazy you have $x(0)=0$ and $y(0)=0$ and $x'(0) = v_0 \cos \theta$ and $y'(0) = v_0 \sin\theta$.

Comment: Thanks. I wonder where did you got the $\frac{m^2g}{k^2}$ term?

Comment: @Crazy $\displaystyle \int gte^{kt/m} \ \mathrm dt = \frac mkg \int t \ \mathrm de^{kt/m} = \frac mkg \left(t e^{kt/m} - \int e^{kt/m} \ \mathrm dt\right) = \frac mkg \left(t e^{kt/m} - \frac mk e^{kt/m}\right)$